# How to redirect TCP traffic from one virtual machine to another in Linux?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, iptables, tcp

What is the simplest way to redirect all TCP traffic from one virtual machine to another in Ubuntu Linux and reverse? And what type of connection I suppose to use in VirtualBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to direct traffic from VM A to VM B, you can set the ip address of VM B to be the default gateway for VM A. That way, when VM A tries to talk to the outside world, it will look up the gateway, and send traffic to VM B.

Put both machines on the same Virtual Box network. Either both bridged, or on the same internal network. They need to see each other.